# drake::vis_drake_graph and drake::make() fail when regex string variables are defined within the plan

Tags: r, regex, error-handling

First, thank you for this amazing package!

I am applying a long list of treatments to a huge corpus of texts.

Before I even begin working with the corpus, I have to load lexicons from csv files and define regex replacement strings using those lexicons. I, therefore, have to put the [import lexicon] > [define regex strings] process within the drake plan, as the lexicons are often updated upstream.

The regex strings are defined as variables, such as:

`nt_left = "(?:[.”]\\s*)"`

Unfortunately, `drake` sends this error when drawing the dependency graph (`vis_drake_graph`) or building the plan (`make`):

```
Error in base::parse(text = code, keep.source = FALSE) :
  <text>:1:3: ':' unexpected
1: (?:
          ^
```

How can I avoid getting those errors, considering I am not able to further escape the regex, as it works as is.